# Content between angular brackets is thrown away silently by Erlang's common_test framework

Tags: erlang

When I use io:format/2 to print some information, I find content between angular brackets is thrown away silently.

Please see the following example:
1) The test suite

```
-module(ioformat_SUITE).
-compile(export_all).
all() ->
    [test_ioformat].

test_ioformat(_) ->
    Expected = 
        [
         <<"NoMethod <ATestMessage>\r\n">>
        ],
    io:format("ExpectedASCII:~n~p~n",[Expected]),
    io:format("ExpectedBINARY:~n~w~n",[Expected]).
```

2) Run the test suite
ct_run -suite ioformat_SUITE

3) Check the log for the test case

ExpectedASCII:

[<<"NoMethod \r\n">>]

ExpectedBINARY:
[<<78,111,77,101,116,104,111,100,32,60,65,84,101,115,116,77,101,115,115,97,103,101,62,13,10>>]

=== Ended at 2012-09-03 08:48:04

4) We can see that there is no "ATestMessage" existing in the log. This content is thrown away by common_test silently.

Is this a bug in common_test? Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure Common Test is not eating your message.
If you're opening the log in a browser, look at the page source code. I bet your HTML tag is there, simply not rendered by the browser.
What about:

```
Expected = 
    [
     <<"NoMethod &lt;ATestMessage&gt;\r\n">>
    ],
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! This is the real reason.